# pytest-bdd--> Selenium Webdriver python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute_script' calling pytest fixture from conftest.py

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, fixtures, pytest-bdd

Got this error when calling the webdriver object; this has been defined within a fixture. Please refer to the below details:

**Code structure**:

tests

features

```
design.feature
```

step_defs

```
__init__.py

conftest.py

test1.py
```

**Code in design.feature:**

```
Feature:
 As a user I want to do something...etc

Scenario: Create design
    Given the user log in to "Electric"
    When set the map area 52.21623,0.12519
```

**Code in test1.py:**

```
scenario('../features/design.feature', 'Create design')

def test_create_design():
    pass


@given(parsers.parse('the user log in to "{name}"'), target_fixture='browser')
def login(browser, name: str):
    browser.get(login_url)
    browser.maximize_window()
    username_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-user")))
    username_box.send_keys(username)
    password_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-pass")))
    password_box.send_keys(password)
    elm = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login-submission")))
    elm.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if name == 'Electric':
        elm = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='ui-layout-center ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center']/"
                                                  "div[@id='app_options' ]/*[@class='box app_options_box'][2]")))
        elm.click()

    elif name == "Configuration":
        elm = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='ui-layout-center ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center']/"
                           "div[@id='app_options' ]/*[@class='box app_options_box']"))
        )
        elm.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    


@when(parsers.parse('set the map area {lat},{long}'))
def set_map_area_and_center(browser, lat: float, long: float):

    print('you are here')
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.execute_script(f"myw.app.map.setView(myw.latLng({lat}, {long}))")
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.quit()
```

**Code in conftest.py:**

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    w = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield w
    w.quit()
```

**Result:**

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute_script' when function set_map_area_and_center is run--> at line browser.execute_script. This makes me think somehow the object is not returned from browser fixture?
fixture browser is working when called first time in function login.

**Expected result:**

to be able to call the fixture within conftest.py or test1.py as many times is needed.

Can anybody help me understand why in the first instance(function login) fixture browser worked and second time (function set_map_area_and_center) didn't and how to solve this issue? Cheers.

**Notes:**

- already saw this topic: [Selenium Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593652/selenium-python-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-keys). can't figure out what is the issue in my case
- all the necessary imports are in place
- webdriver has been "yielded", to get the object

Comment: anybody, any idea is appreciated

Comment: Where is the `@when` decorator coming from?

Comment: Hi @Keith, I have updated the details about the code. "when" decorator comes from design.feature file and is inside the Scenario. Please refer to the above code. If you need any other info, please give me a shout.

Comment: It looks like the pytest fixture is going through a Selenium decorator. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, basically decorators "given" and "when" are special pytest-bdd decorators in which steps from Scenario are defined. the weird thing is that in "given", when calling "browser" does not complain but second time, in "when", says basically that browser is of "None" type @Keith

Comment: yes, I am not sure I can help here, since I haven't used pytest-bdd. I noticed the other one has the `target_fixture` option, but the second doesn't.

Comment: I'm suspicious that the decorator is altering it, or closing it.

Comment: the second doesn't because only the given needs to have it-is mandatory, when, does not need to include the target_fixture. The problem here is the webdriver object, I think second time somehow, does not find it; this has nothing to do with the decorator but, I think with how the fixture has been created and called. @Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at @given decorator, should not be target_fixture, this will "create" and use another fixture call browser-in my case and, second time when @when decorator wants to use the browser fixture, pytest will raise an error because, basically sees it created 2 times with the same name and does not recognize it, hence the "None" type.
To work, instead of:

```
@given(parsers.parse('the user log in to "{name}"'), target_fixture='browser')
def login(browser, name: str):
    browser.get(login_url)
```

should be:

```
@given(parsers.parse('the user log in to "{name}"'))
def login(browser, name: str):
    browser.get(login_url)
```